# como podria insertar una plantilla html dentro de otra en angular?

Tags: html, angular

tengo una componente Componente1 y otra llamada Componente2 lo que quiero saber es como podría hacer para llamar la plantilla html de Componente2 en el html de Componente1, algo así:

```html
plantilla de componente1:
<html>
  <Componente2> </Componente2> 

</html>
```

Tal cual como se hace en el app.component.html, lo que quiero hacer es para ahorrar código en la Componente1 ya que uso mucho código repetitivo y lo que quiero es insertar el componente2. como podría hacerlo? estoy comenzando con Angular, debo importar la componente2 en la componente1 ? cuales serían los pasos a seguir? seria una buena practica para reusar código?

Answer (score 1):

Todo parte de index.html el cual por defecto tienes app-root como etiqueta mostrando el render del html app.component.html, si se quiere ampliar... Crea un nuevo componente :

```
ng generate component compomenteB
```

Si nos fijamos lo habra añadido en appModule su import necesario y dentro de componenteB.component.ts veras en el selector

```
@Component
```

Que tiene una propiedad templateUrl, el cual asocia a su "render" de html por lo tanto... Dentro del app.component.html colocaras la etiqueta del componenteB...

Definida en la propiedad selector del decorador @Component

Happy Conding !!

Comment: Hola Joel, gracias por responder. Pero me refería exactamente a importar una componente dentro de otra. Se que todo parte del app. En el app.html tengo varias componentes, pero si yo dentro de una de esas componentes quiere llamar a otra como podría hacer? Lo que quiero es tratar de reusar código, ya que tengo una componente donde uso mucho código repetitivo y lo quiero tener en una componen aparte para solo hacer llamadas de esa componen y no tener tanto código repetido.

Comment: Compañero pues tan sencillo como repetir la etiqueta, componenteB en el html de app y ya podrias usarlo tanto como quieras =) es la gracia de angular

Answer (score 1):

Fijate que cuando creas un proyecto Angular se crea con un index.html. Dentro de ese index.html hay una etiqueta que es `<app-root></app-root>` dentro del body. Esa etiqueta lo que hace es "decirle" a angular que todo lo que mostrará está en el archivo app.component.html. Para crear un nuevo componente y enlazarlo al app.component.html lo que debes hacer es escribir en la terminal `ng g c components/nombredelcomponentenuevo` Se lo divide en una carpeta de componentes para estár más organizado (asi lo hago yo).

Answer (score 0):

según entiendo lo que queres hacer es que por ejemplo, en el `Componente2` se visualice el HTML del `componente1`. Esto es muy fácil y prácticamente igual al código que nos pusiste como ejemplo

Tal como vos dijiste dentro del template de nuestro `componente1` podríamos insertar el tag (declarado como selector) que le corresponda al `componente2` y de esa manera visualizar ambos templates en conjunto.

A modo de ejmplo, podemos ver el HTML de X componente :

```
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <h3 class="text-left text-secondary"><i>Contact Update</i></h3>
  <br>
</div>
```

A su vez tenemos otro componente llamado `MainpageComponent` cuyo selector es `app-mainpage` , aquí el .ts del componente:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mainpage',
  templateUrl: './mainpage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mainpage.component.css']
})
export class MainpageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
```

Al momento de querer acoplar el HTML de MainpageComponent a nuestro primer componente X, sólo debemos colocar el tag selector de MainpageComponent de la siguiente manera y listo! :

```
<app-mainpage></app-mainpage>
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <h3 class="text-left text-secondary"><i>Contact Update</i></h3>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: creí que había que hacer algún tipo de importación en la componente donde quería usar alguna otro componente.

Comment: No, es tan sencillo como eso!, solamente tendrías que declararlo en el apartado spec (de los test) , pero no es el caso! jaja, si te sirvió espero tu punto para arriba y el tilde! saludos.

Comment: a que te refieres con que tendría que declararlo en el apartado spec? probe simplemente añadiendo el tag del selector y funcionó, para que sería eso que mencionas?

Comment: Lo que mencioné es para cuando queres realizar tests del componente, lo ves en el apartado NombreComponente.spec.ts